# How can I fill in a column with a specified value if it is in the range of another two column values?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, panel-data

I have one data frame A with values for start year and end year, where ccode identifies the unit

```
ccode StartYear1 EndYear1
 2       1950     1953
 2       1965     1973
```

and another dataframe B that has one observation per ccode and per year

```
ccode  year
  2    1950
  2    1951
  2    1952
  2    1953
  2    1954
  2    1955
```

I would like to add a new variable in the second dataframe that is equal to one for each year in the range from StartYear1 to EndYear1, matched by the variable "ccode". So the output should be data frame B

```
ccode  year  flag
  2    1950    1
  2    1951    1
  2    1952    1
  2    1953    1
  2    1954    0
  2    1955    0
```

I have tried the following code

```
dfB <-
  dfB %>%
  group_by(ccode,year) %>%
  mutate(flag= year %in% list(seq(dfA$StartYear1,dfA$EndYear1)))
```

but I can't figure out how to assign the value "1" to years in this range. How can I assign a specific value if a row is in list(seq(StartYear1,EndYear1))? Thanks!

UPDATE***

Akrun, I ran your code and got the following results

```
 ccode  year  flag
      2    1950    1
      2    1951    1
      2    1952    1
      2    1953    1
      2    1954    1
      2    1955    1
```

which should be

```
 ccode  year  flag
      2    1950    1
      2    1951    1
      2    1952    1
      2    1953    1
      2    1954    0
      2    1955    0
```

Should there be a group_by referencing either the ccode or the years?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2` from `purrr` to create the sequence and then check whether that sequence values are `%in%` the second dataset 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- dfA %>%
        mutate(yearfull = map2(StartYear1, EndYear1, `:`)) %>%
        unnest(c(yearfull))

dfB %>% 
     mutate(flag = +(year %in% df1$yearfull))
#  ccode year flag
#1     2 1950    1
#2     2 1951    1
#3     2 1952    1
#4     2 1953    1
#5     2 1954    0
#6     2 1955    0
```

#### data

```
dfA <- structure(list(ccode = c(2L, 2L), StartYear1 = c(1950L, 1965L
), EndYear1 = c(1953L, 1973L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

dfB <- structure(list(ccode = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), year = 1950:1955), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Just ran your update, but I got some values that are incorrect. I'll keep trying and reply with code when it works. Thanks so much for your help!